# populate JavaFX ListView

Tags: maven, javafx, fxml

The ListView does not show what I expected.

I have just started to use *JavaFX* using *Maven* and *Fxml*. And I am wondering, why my data does not show up.

I followed several tutorials, also searched here, but can not pinpoint my fault. For sure it should be simple.

**The App**:

```
package eu.ngong.sampleFxml;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("primary.fxml")).load(), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**The Controller**:

```
package eu.ngong.sampleFxml;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class PrimaryController implements Initializable {

    String[] values = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> theList;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        this.theList.getItems().addAll(values);

    };

}
```

**Fxml file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox id="primary" alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="970.0" prefWidth="966.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="eu.ngong.sampleFxml.PrimaryController">
   <children>
      <Label text="Primary View" />
      <ListView id="theList" fx:id="theList" minHeight="100.0" minWidth="926.0" prefHeight="893.0" prefWidth="926.0">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </ListView>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eu.ngong</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleFxml</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>eu.ngong.sampleFxml.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This results to

[image]

while I expected to see the words "one", "two", "three", "four", "five".

You may also

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/ngong1/samplefxml.git
```

Comment: It is not your issue, but I'd advise using the latest stable releases rather than the `ea` releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never a good idea to hard-code sizes in JavaFX (or, indeed, in any responsive UI toolkit). Let the layout panes size the components accordingly, and use the API for the layout panes to control how that is done, if needed.

In your case you make the minimum width of the `ListView` 926 pixels:

```
  <ListView id="theList" fx:id="theList" minHeight="100.0" minWidth="926.0" prefHeight="893.0" prefWidth="926.0">
```

but you create a `Scene` which is only 640 pixels wide:

```
    scene = new Scene(new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("primary.fxml")).load(), 640, 480);
```

The `ListView` is therefore wider than the scene, so not all of it can be displayed. Since you tell the `VBox` containing the `ListView` to center its content:

```
<VBox id="primary" alignment="TOP_CENTER" ...>
```

the text in the cells in the list view, which is left-aligned by default in those cells, is off-screen to the left.

If you expand the window (stretching the scene) you will actually see it is working just fine:

[image]

As mentioned: it is never a good idea to hard-code sizes. Just remove all those hard-coded sizes from the FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox id="primary" alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.list.PrimaryController">
    <children>
        <Label text="Primary View" />
        <ListView id="theList" fx:id="theList">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
            <padding>
                <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
            </padding>
        </ListView>
    </children>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
    </padding>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Thank you, James. I will look for *Best Practices Programming JavaFX*.